# How can I prevent word wrapping on tab bar items in Holo theme?

Tags: android, styles, themes

My app is running with Theme.Light on API level 10 and lower and Holo.Light on API level 11 and higher. The tab bar in Theme Light shows all items without any word wrap, but the Holo theme wraps them in the middle of the word:

[image: holo theme screenshot]

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `android:ellipsize` attribute in the xml or
`setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt)` on the view holding the text ? If the view inherits from or are a text view that should work.
"If set, causes words that are longer than the view is wide to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle."
Perhaps you can set a TextView as TabSpec by using `public TabHost.TabSpec setIndicator (View view)`

Comment: I don't really want to elipsize the text. A slightly smaller padding would be nice though. I tried messing with SetIndicator (myCustomView), but so far I have failed (the tab always stayed empty).

Comment: You could drop the Tabs al togeather and use a ViewPager and and Idicator on top of it, like in the example:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator
To see how that looks you can download "ViewPagerIndicator" from the market, just to see a demo of it.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS52aWV3cGFnZXJpbmRpY2F0b3Iuc2FtcGxlIl0.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Manage this, with

Override this class in project ActionBarSherlock ./ActionbarSherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ScrollingTabContainerView.java

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if (mParent.mMaxTabWidth > 0 && getMeasuredWidth() > mParent.mMaxTabWidth) {

        //comment this line

       // super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mParent.mMaxTabWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),heightMeasureSpec);

       //now do nothing , override by me for ActionBarTabs not rezize never
      //this method manage the size tabs, if you want you can count caracters to resize the size width
    }
}
```